CLion `find in files` action triggers a sudden logout in Kubuntu22.04
I came across a weird problem on Kubuntu22.04.
After opening my CLion and selecting Edit -> Find -> Find in Files action, when I tried to type some word to find, the system suddenly got black screen and logged out. Some error message displays:
0.251917] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.PB2],
0.251929] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
0.779866] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
1.035375] ACPI BIOS Error(bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM.AFN7], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
1.035419] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
/dev/nvmeOn1p2: clean, 232457/31162368 files, 92451620/124645632 blocks
3.913807]

By the way, my laptop uses NVIDIA discrete graphics card.
I cannot really figure out what CLion has to do with the system logout, can any body please help me ? I can provide more infos if you like. Thanks in advance!

There was a new release of Xorg in 2024-04-05 due a security issue: ESB-2024.2065 and related packages that introduced a bug in a function IntelliJ (Webstrom, CLion, and so on) uses. This cause Xorg to crash in very specific situations. IntelliJ implementation of text anti-aliasing is one of those cases for example.
I was having that issue of Xorg crashing when I did something in Webstrom 2024.1, that started after a system upgrade + upgrading to Webstorm 2024.1, and in this post, another user have a very similar issue, where arthur answer solved the issue in my case (please pay attention to the coments if you use KDE)
I have even opened a bug report on JetBrains, if you want to reproduce my steps to see if is the same stuff.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks! Downgrading xserver-xorg-core, xserver-common,xwayland as what @artur posted here seems to fix the issue.
